# sending mail via PowerShell - user & pass

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to develop one script for sending some emails. I succeed to do this but only for gmail and it works.

I now need to integrate the script in our company network, how can I handle my login user and pass in this script? When I'm connecting to company network this script is not working and I think is because of my login use and pass and other thing's that I do not know.

```
$email = "sender.mail@gmail.com" 
$pass = "sender.mail.pass" 
$smtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"

$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage 
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer) 
$smtp.EnableSsl = $true 
$msg.From = "$email"  
$msg.To.Add("receiver.mail@Xcorporation.com")
$msg.BodyEncoding = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8 
$msg.SubjectEncoding = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8 
$msg.IsBodyHTML = $true  
$msg.Subject = "Test mail from PowerShell" 
$msg.Body = "This mail is sended automatically from PowerShel script"  
$SMTP.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("$email", "$pass"); 
$smtp.Send($msg)
```

Comment: Why is the script not working? If it works at home, but not work, it's probably a firewall and/or networking issue that'll you'll need to resolve with your IT department.

Comment: Credentials on a corporate network will likely be your username (likely `domain\username` if a Microsoft based network) rather than your email. You'll need to speak to your IT Support team to verify these.

Comment: Yes, I know that I need to handle new thing when I want to integrate in our network, I need to handle this new credentials instead of my e-mail but for the moment I do not know how to do this, I need to study more about this. My question is, can you guy's help me with some hints ? What new parameter's should I add ? Thank you for support !

Comment: Hello guys, I want to tell you that now, this script is working for me. The only problem was that I do not use the right SmtpServer for me. For who want to use also this code : please be carefully when you chose Server name, EnableSsl - true or false ( default is false ), encoding type for Body and Subject  !!! Thank you guys for support !

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage) you may find it a lot easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add as a reference, in case there's someone with an aggressive corporation firewall not allowing, e.g. Google's SMTP service.

Here's a snippet for using [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com)'s email [Rest API](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/mail-send) for sending emails:

```
$sendEmailUrl = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send"
$apiKey = "<insert api key here>"

$headers = @{}
$headers.Add("Authorization","Bearer $apiKey")

$ct = "application/json"

$jsonRequest = [ordered]@{
   personalizations= @(@{
    to = @(
        @{
            email = "<email address of recipient>"
            name = "<name of recipient>"
        }
    )
    subject = "hello world!"
  })
  from = @{
    email = "sam.smith@example.com"
    name = "Sam Smith"
  }
  reply_to = @{
    email = "sam.smith@example.com"
    name = "Sam Smith"
  }
  content = @(
    @{
        type = "text/plain"
        value ="just a test email"
    }
  )
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post `
    -Headers $headers `
    -Body $jsonRequest `
    -ContentType $ct `
    -Uri $sendEmailUrl
```

For reference, SendGrid has a free email service [offering for Azure subscribers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email#create-a-sendgrid-account) offering to send 25000 free emails per month.

Comment: Sorry , but is my first time when I hear about this program/tool and about Azure, can you please help me with more details or with some hints/examples ? Thank you for your support !

Comment: SendGrid is a commercial service offering SMTP as a service. You get both a SMTP and rest API endpoint you can call from your own code. The are several available plans also, all commercial. If you are a subscriber of Microsoft Azure, then you can register a free plan allowing you to send 25000 mails per month, for free. Example I posted use the rest API, I thought it would be useful to show how you can send email in case there's a firewall blocking services like Google's SMTP